# Python program to list all folders with date modified

Tags: python-3.x

I need a Python program to list all folders with date modified. When I run it, all of the modification dates are the same. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
import os, time, stat

path = 'h:\\lance\\'

folders = []

r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for folder in d:

        modTimesinceEpoc = os.path.getctime(path)
        modificationTime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(modTimesinceEpoc))

        folders.append(os.path.join(r, folder))

[0:5] just grabs the first 5 folders, helpful if the total amount of folders is large

for f in folders [0:5]:
    print(f, "Last Modified Time : ", modificationTime)
```

Output:

> h:\lance\Return series project Last Modified Time :  2019-09-23 
>   h:\lance\Forecast Pro Last Modified Time :  2019-09-23 
>   h:\lance\Custom Price Files Last Modified Time :  2019-09-23
>   h:\lance\MBO and responsibilities Last Modified Time :  2019-09-23
>   h:\lance.vscode Last Modified Time :  2019-09-23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
import os, time, stat

path = 'h:\\lance\\'

folders = []

# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for folder in d:
        location = os.path.join(r, folder)
        modTimesinceEpoc = os.path.getctime(location)
        modificationTime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(modTimesinceEpoc))
        folders.append((location, modificationTime))

# [0:5] just grabs the first 5 folders, helpful if the total amount of folders is large

for f in folders[:5]:
    print(f)
```